# Msbuild clickonce application error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, clickonce

I have a clickonce application if i run it in some PC's i get an error. I have attached an image.

But the same build works on that machine but fails in other machines. whats the solution for the same. [image]

Comment: Have you checked what version of the .Net framework is installed on the working PCs compared to the non-working ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Solution Explorer > Your Project > Properties > Publish > Application Files and set that assembly stated in the error message to "Include".

Comment: You can also enable logging for clickonce deployment if you are encountering more problems:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404265.aspx

Comment: Testing the changes .. but why does this happen ?

Comment: You need to copy the assemblies you used to the application files after publish , so that when you install it on a different PC it continues to work. This is why you include them in the publish process.